# Integers and functional equation

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Let $\Bbb{Z}^+$be the set of all non-negative integers where $n$ and $k$ are given natural numbers. We consider the following non-decreasing function,

$$f:\Bbb{Z}^+ \to \Bbb{Z}^+$$ such that

\begin{align}
f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}^{n}\right) 
=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(f(a_{i})\right)^{n}\\
\end{align}

1.Find all functions for $n=2014$ and $k=2014^{2013}$

2.Find, number of functions which satisfy the condition of the problem
depending on the values ​​of parameters $n$ and $k$.

Comment: @Travis, this question is not answered there (answer is not full)

Comment: @santoni7 Then you could ask there for someone to complete it, not sure why you think starting a duplicate will solve the problem.

Comment: I know, but the question is still a duplicate, and having two threads for the same question will make it harder, not easier, to access discussion of it.